# 'Get 30 days ago' and 'one year ago' date in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I am getting current date using below code :

```
<#assign aDateTime = .now>
<#assign aDate = aDateTime?date>
current date: ${aDate?iso_utc}
```

How to 'get 30 days ago' and 'one year ago' date using freemarker ?

Comment: I assume you do it by doing math on `aDateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer.
Find freeemarker code below :

```html
<#assign currentDate = .now>
Current Date : ${currentDate?date}<br>
<#assign numberOfDays = 30?long>
<#assign timeInMillisecond = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * numberOfDays) >
<#assign aDate = currentDate?long - timeInMillisecond?long>
<#assign Diff = aDate?long>
<#assign thirtyDaysBeforeDate = Diff?number_to_date>
<br>Date before ${numberOfDays} Days : ${thirtyDaysBeforeDate}<br>
<br>Date before ${numberOfDays} Days in UTC format : ${thirtyDaysBeforeDate?iso_utc}<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a date/time/datetime to milliseconds since the epoch like `aDateTime?long`. Then you can subtract those values from each other and divide them with the length of a day or of a year. And if you need this for multiple times, pack it into a `#function` or `#macro`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in Freemarker for that:

```
<#function dateDiff date days>
    <#assign timeInMilliseconds = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days) >
    <#assign aDate = date?long - timeInMilliseconds?long>
    <#return aDate?number_to_date>
</#function>
```

An you can use like this:

```
date: ${date?string('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')}
date 10 days ago: ${dateDiff(date, 10)?string('dd.MM.yyyy')}
```

This will print out:

```
date: 25.07.2018 20:01:35
date 10 days ago: 15.07.2018
```